# vba delete chart series if name series exist

Tags: excel, vba

Series name in chart is test. I want to delete the serie if "te" is part of the series name and tried following code, but it doesn't work.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
 
Dim n As Series
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
'    If Right(.SeriesCollection.Name, 3) = "te" Then            Doesn't work
'    If n.Name = "*te*" Then     Works with "test", but not with "te"
        n.Delete
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: You have to use `LIKE` - read the according documentation/help

Comment: and the `n` way.  You can use `INSTR` too to see if the string contains `te`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about the like-Operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) - you have to use it similar to the equal sign:

```vb
Dim n As Series
For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    If n.Name Like "*te*" Then
        n.Delete
    End If
Next n
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'm a beginner. I tried Like, but that doesn't work As I have it now

```
Dim n As Series
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection

    If n.Like = "te" Then
    n.Delete
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: You shouldn't post this as an answer but edit your question instead.

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: Don't forget the wildcards in Ike's answer.